# js function not working properly, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The  function isn't working when i'm using `$(document).ready(function () {  ..... });`
but it works when i invoke. please take a look.

```
#test {height:25%,width:25% }

<body>
....
<div id="test">
  <image src="file.jpg" />
</div>
...
</div> </body>
```

***js file (Not working) :***

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
   $('#test').draggable();
 });
```

***js file (Working when a function is invoked)***

```
function startDrag() {    // I just called this function from html files e.g. <div id="test" onmouseover="startDrag();">....</div>
 $('#test').draggable();
}
```

Comment: It may depends on where is your code, so try putting it above or down your image code.

Comment: How is your js file included?

Comment: @Gary: <head> <script type="text/javascript"  src="testDrag/portlet.js"> </script> </head>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if this is something that relies on the document being 'loaded' as opposed to 'ready'

Does the following work?

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#test').draggable();
}
```

Also, try including your JS File at the foot of your page (i.e. below the #test html)

Answer (score 0):

Both should work. I suggest to open the JavaScript debugger and set a breakpoint to see when and if the code is executed.

Also check the console for any errors. Maybe it's a silly typo somewhere,

Comment: yes, you are right. I guess it'd be typo mistake because the same function works with another div id.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
$(function () { 
    $('#test').draggable();
});
```

It might not make a difference, but this is the way I'm used to :)